# What is the difference between <body style="background-color:red;"> and <body bgcolor="red">?

Tags: css, html, tags

I am a beginner in programming. First I learnt to change background color by

```
<body bgcolor="blue">
```

tag. But later I found an example with

```
<body style="background-color:red;">
```

this kind of tag.

The output looks the same to me. Why do we use style attribute then? I looked up on google but didn't find anything. But I found that it is somehow related to CSS. What is the relation between HTML and CSS? Aren't they two different languages?

Comment: HTML isn't a programming language

Comment: bgcolor is back from the days of HTML2. We're up to 5 now.

Comment: And please merge your text into one question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bgcolor is a HTML attribute and is not supported by HTML5. As of now all the latest browsers support `<body bgcolor="color">` but it may change in future.

`<body style="background:red">`
is CSS way of applying background and is better way to do it.

Comment: To add to this, its best to separate style from markup when possible. Put your CSS in a stylesheet and include that stylesheet in your HTML by using the `<link>` tag. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

Both the things do the same thing (you may have noticed that) but the only difference is both of them are from different languages, one is from CSS and the other from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

So it  is no longer used (or should not be used) as it is deprecated and no longer a standard

Earlier html was used for both content and styling of webpages, but now we have
**HTML** - For **content** only
**CSS** - For **style**

even though browsers will style run all non standard code because some of the old websites or apps might still be using that "*non standard code*" , but you **shouldnt** and please learn css if you want to add style to your website